# yq - Nest existing values

Tags: yaml, yq

Using mikefarah/yq v4, how can I take an existing YAML document and nest it under a new heading?

```yaml
value1: foo
value2: bar
```

should become

```yaml
newHeading:
  value1: foo
  value2: bar
```

Comment: Did you try `yq '{"newHeading": .}' file.yaml`?

Comment: Solved ^^. Thank you @pmf

Answer (score 0):

Per @pmf comment:

```
yq '{"newHeading": .}' file.yaml
```